# why the reference don't put into reference queue when finalize method overrided

Tags: java, reference, finalize

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A aObject = new A();

        ReferenceQueue<A> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        PhantomReference<A> weak = new PhantomReference<>(aObject, queue);

        aObject = null;
        System.gc();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        System.out.println(queue.poll());
    }
}

class A{
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.finalize();

        System.out.println("finalize");
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
finalize
null
```

but if i delete the finalize method in class A, the result is：

```
java.lang.ref.PhantomReference@5b2c9e5d
```

so, the result shows that when I override the finalize method, the weak object isn't put into the reference queue, is that because the aObject resurrected? But I don't do anything in the finalize method

Comment: Some additional information: uncommenting either `super.finalize()` or `System.out.println(...)` does not change the behaviour. Uncommenting the whole body of method leads to the expected behaviour. Placing both `super.finalize()` and `System.out.println(...)` in an `if (false) { ... }` will also result in the expected behaviour, whereas placing both statement in an `if (true) { ... }` will also result in the unexpected behaviour. Tested with Oracle java 1.8.0_151. Maybe this is somewhat useful.

Comment: Are you sure that this not caused by an entropy in a multi-threaded environment? Does running this test repeatedly in a loop always produce the same result?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov just did some testing. Repeating the code in a loop does not change the outcome (I repeated each constellation 100 times). The application is definitively single-threaded.

Comment: @Turing85, this contradicts the Javadoc which states that `gc` (and, consequently, the finalizers) run in separate thread to the one which user starts.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it is single-threaded w.r.t. the user-threads. The JVM, of course, does spawn other threads out of the programmer's control.

Comment: @Turing85, when talking about multithreaded environment, here I'm referrign to exactly this: while the application is single-threaded, the application + GC is not, there are at least two threads here. Just noticed there, can you please remove `sleep` call and try running it again?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I could edit the question and add all the information I have gathered so far, but I feel this would be like "stealing" the question from OP. I myself are waiting for a response of OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a nontrivial `finalize`, Java knows the object is unreachable* before `finalize` runs, but it doesn't know the object is *still* unreachable after `finalize`.

It has to wait for the object to be deemed unreachable again in another GC cycle before it can enqueue the phantom reference.

<sup>*not quite unreachable in the terminology of the [java.lang.ref docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability), but neither strongly, softly, nor weakly reachable</sup>

Comment: What exactly counts as "nontrivial"? What threw me off was that `public void finalize() { super.finalize(); }` seems to be "too complex", but `public void finalize() { if (false) { super.finalize(); } }` is fine.

Comment: @Turing85: I believe that's left up to the implementation. The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6) only says "For efficiency, an implementation may keep track of classes that do not override the finalize method of class Object, or override it in a trivial way. We encourage implementations to treat such objects as having a finalizer that is not overridden, and to finalize them more efficiently, as described in §12.6.1."

Comment: @Turing85 `public void finalize() { if (false) { super.finalize(); } }` is almost certainly identified as containing dead code by the compiler and ends up being equivalent to the trivial empty override.

Comment: @Hulk I know. But the compiler should also recognize that `public void finalize() { super.finalize(); }` is effectively a non-overwritten method.

Comment: @Turing85 a compiler can not remove an explicit method declaration, as that has an impact on the accessibility of that method (the `protected` method `Object.finalize()` can only be accessed by subclasses via `super` invocation, the overridden method can be accessed by all classes within the same package, even if you didn’t use `public`). So there is a compiled method which, of course, must retain the `super.finalize()` invocation. In contrast, removing `if(false) { …}` statements at compile-time has no impact (other than making `finalize()` a trivial empty method).

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting observation. Here is what is happening:

When class has [non-trivial](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml) (non empty in OP case) `finalize` method the JVM will create a `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` (which is a subclass of `Reference`) object and point it to our referent, in this case A object. This in turn will prevent `PhantomReference` to enqueue it since A is already referenced by `Finalizer`.

This was observer by me in debugger using Java 1.8 and also described in detail [here](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml).

The observation from @Turing85 is expected since when we remove all statements inside `finalize` method it becomes [trivial](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml) and behaves just like any class without `finalize` method and wont be referenced by `Finalizer`.

**Update:**

The question was asked if `Finalizer` will clear its reference to A at all. The JVM does clear it on the subsequent GC runs, which in turn finally allows `PhantomReference` to enqueue A into its reference queue.

For example running the below code with non-trivial `finalize` method will get non null `PhantomReference` from its reference queue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    A aObject = new A();

    ReferenceQueue<A> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    PhantomReference<A> pr = new PhantomReference<>(aObject, queue);

    aObject = null;
    System.gc();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

    System.gc();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

    System.out.println( queue.poll() );
}
```

Prints:

```
finalize 
java.lang.ref.PhantomReference@15db9742
```

Comment: A is referenced by Finalizer, then when will the reference be cleared?

Comment: The `Finalizer` gets cleared explicitly at the end of [the `runFinalizer` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ref/Finalizer.java#90) though this is usually not even necessary, as no-one is going to keep a reference to the `Finalizer` anyway, so it simply gets garbage collected afterwards. When a `Reference` object is not enqueued and not otherwise reachable, it gets collected like an ordinary Java object and doesn’t count as reference at all.